# Hide and show DIV with javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do an event for hide and show with pure Javascript **string** parameters. I want to hide the other div once one of them is displayed (Let's say there are multiple div).

I tried to do it my own but I only managed to display once clicked. I had no idea how to hide the rest and only show that specified div.

Below is my code:

```js
function show(id) {
  if (document.getElementById('div_'+id).style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById('div_'+id).style.display = 'block';
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.title {
  border:1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title" onclick="show('first');">Title 1</div>
<div class="content" id="div_first" style="display:none;">Content 1
</div>

<div class="title" onclick="show('sec');">Title 2</div>
<div class="content" id="div_sec" style="display:none;">Content 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `data-*` attribute to store the target selector.
- Don't use inline `on*` handlers. Keep your JS in one place.
- Use CSS `.is-active` to manipulate the *visibility* state like `display: block;`

```js
const showBtn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-show]');
const content = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

function show(ev) {
  const selector = ev.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-show');
  const elToShow = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  content.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('is-active'));
  elToShow.forEach(el => el.classList.add('is-active'));
}

showBtn.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', show));
```

```css
.title {
  border:1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;  /* ADD THIS */
}

.content.is-active{ /* ADD THIS */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="title" data-show="#content-1">Title 1</div>
<div class="title" data-show="#content-2">Title 2</div>

<div class="content" id="content-1">Content 1</div>
<div class="content" id="content-2">Content 2</div>
```

Comment: If `selector` is an `id` why use `querySelectorAll` and then `.forEach()`? Couldn't you use `querySelector` and then remove the need for the `.forEach` entirely since there should only be one element with that selector id?

Comment: @Nick You answered your own question. data-show can now be any selector. Why limit yourself on IDs. Have multiple elements with same class? Bam.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of the id or element that is being displayed so that you can hide it if another one is selected. There's no need to iterate over them to hide them all, as you will know which one is being displayed, or to query the DOM each time to get the current one, as you can just keep a reference to it the first time.

I have updated the logic to toggle them if you click the same one twice and removed the inline event listeners, which I've moved to JS.

Note I have also replaced the `<div>`s for the `.title` elements with `<button>`s, as they will work better with keyboard navigation, mouse events and screen readers. You could also use `<a>`s instead.

```js
let currentContentTab = null;

function show(e) {
  // Using e.target you can get a reference to the clicked button:
  const contentTab = document.getElementById(`div${ e.target.id.substring(3) }`);
  const isHidden = contentTab.style.display === 'none';
  
  // Toggle the panel we have just clicked (assuming you want to allow closing all of them again):
  contentTab.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
  
  // Hide the previous one, if any:
  if (currentContentTab) {    
    currentContentTab.style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  // Keep track of the one we are currently displaying:
  currentContentTab = isHidden ? contentTab : null;
}

// No need to have inline JS, you can bind the event listeners from JS:
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('.title')) button.onclick = show;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.title {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 8px;
  outline: none;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button class="title" id="tab1">Title 1</button>
<button class="title" id="tab2">Title 2</button>
<button class="title" id="tab3">Title 3</button>
<button class="title" id="tab4">Title 4</button>

<div class="content" id="div1" style="display:none; ">
  Content 1...
</div>

<div class="content" id="div2" style="display:none; ">
  Content 2...
</div>

<div class="content" id="div3" style="display:none; ">
  Content 3...
</div>

<div class="content" id="div4" style="display:none; ">
  Content 4...
</div>
```

If accessibility is important for you, you might want to add some [ARIA attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) and the [HTML `hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden):

```js
let currentTab = null;
let currentPanel = null;

function show(e) {
  const tab = e.target;
  const id = tab.getAttribute('aria-controls');
  const panel = document.getElementById(id);
    
  // Toggle the panel we have just clicked:
  tab.toggleAttribute('aria-selected');
  panel.toggleAttribute('hidden');
       
  // Hide the previous one, if any:
  if (currentTab) {    
    currentTab.removeAttribute('aria-selected');
    currentPanel.setAttribute('hidden', true);
  }
  
  // Keep track of the one we are currently displaying:      
  if (currentTab === tab) {
    currentTab = null;
    currentPanel = null;
  } else {
    currentTab = tab;
    currentPanel = panel;
  }
}

for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('.title')) button.onclick = show;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.title {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 8px;
  outline: none;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button class="title" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="div1" id="tab1">Title 1</button>
<button class="title" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="div2" id="tab2">Title 2</button>
<button class="title" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="div3" id="tab3">Title 3</button>
<button class="title" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="div4" id="tab4">Title 4</button>

<div class="content" id="div1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelby aria-labelledby="tab1" hidden>
  Content 1...
</div>

<div class="content" id="div2"role="tabpanel" aria-labelby aria-labelledby="tab2" hidden>
  Content 2...
</div>

<div class="content" id="div3"role="tabpanel" aria-labelby aria-labelledby="tab3" hidden>
  Content 3...
</div>

<div class="content" id="div4"role="tabpanel" aria-labelby aria-labelledby="tab4" hidden>
  Content 4...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This JS code will grab all `.content` divs and will hide them unless it's the one we clicked.

```
function show(id) {
    const el = document.getElementById('div' + id);

  if (el.style.display == 'none') {
    el.style.display = 'block';
  }

  const otherEls = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

  otherEls.forEach(function (elItem) {
    if (el !== elItem) {
        elItem.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution as the following:

```js
function show(id)
{
 var divs=document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  for (i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
  {
   divs[i].style.display='none';
  }
  document.getElementById('div_'+id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.title {
  border:1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title" onclick="show('first');">Title 1</div>
<div class="content" id="div_first" style="display:none;">Content 1
</div>

<div class="title" onclick="show('sec');">Title 2</div>
<div class="content" id="div_sec" style="display:none;">Content 2
</div>
```